# Traverse file vertically

Tags: c++

I need to traverse a file in a vertical manner. If suppose the file contents are:

```
adg
beh
cfi
```

It should print the file as:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

The length for each line will be same(i.e. all lines will be of length 3 for above example). I have written a code but it doesn't traverse the file as required.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream fs;
    fs.open("asd.txt",ios::in);
    string str;
    char *ch = new char();
    int lineLen = 0, k = 0;
    if(getline(fs,str))
    {
        lineLen = str.length();
    }
    fs.seekg(0);
    if(lineLen > 0)
    {
    for(int i = 0;i<lineLen;i++)
    {
        fs.seekg(i+k*lineLen);
        while(fs.read(ch,1))
        {
            k++;
            fs.seekg(i+k*lineLen);
            cout<<*ch;
        }
        k = 0;
    }
    }
    fs.close();
    cin.ignore();
}
```

I am a bit new to file handling and couldn't find the mistake. Also, is there a better approach for this to be followed?

Comment: The problem probably lies within the fact, the the number of characters doesn't correspond exactly to the number of bytes. And that's because when reading a text file a conversion from `\r\n` to `\n` is being made. Try adding `1` to lineLen.

Comment: I have tried it. The output is even more weird then

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: YES. Why would I post a question without debugging. Doesn't my score show that i have been using Stackoverflow for some time.

Comment: You leak memory with ch. If you only need one char, then `char ch[1]` will do.

Comment: @Saksham Number of bytes for newlines depends in your OS and may be causing you trouble. Can you pre-process the file to remove newlines?

Comment: Well if you tried debugging, could you share some information? The problem is so easy that you can count the expected result of each variable on your fingers. Which variable has the wrong value for the first time? For example: `lineLen` should be 4 or 5, and after second for iteration and the `fs.seekg(i+k*lineLine)` what's the first character - should be `d` right? Well, is it?

Comment: @NeilKirk I think you have given me the right direction to think. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if you use SO for so long time, you should know that "output is weird" is a bit vague :) What's the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much your way with some little tweaks

```
//lines = no. of lines in file
fs.seekg(0, fs.beg);
fs.clear(); 
if(lineLen > 0)
{
for(int k = 0; k < lineLen; k++) {
    for(int i = 0;i<lines;i++){
        fs.seekg(k+i * (lineLen + 2), fs.beg); //use lines + 2
        if(fs.read (ch,1));
          cout << *ch; 
    }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I had tried `lineLen+1` but not 2. May I know the reason why 2?? Is it that the null character size is OS dependant?

Comment: @Saksham In your case newline is combination of `CF`& `LF` `(\r\n)`. `lineLen+1` might work too if, if you have saved on linux system. Unix tends to use `\n` as a line separator whereas Windows tends to use `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

You might find this task much simpler if you were to use [`mmap(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html).  There may be a C++ equivalent or wrapper, but I'm afraid I'm not much of an expert on that front.  Hopefully someone will come along with a better answer if that's the case.

Here's a quick C (not ++) example.  I'll see if I can google around and C++ify it some more:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("input", O_RDONLY);

    struct stat s;
    fstat(fd, &s);

    // map the file as one big string
    char *c = mmap(0, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    // calculate sizes
    int columns = strchr(c, '\n') - c; // first newline delimits a row
    int stride = columns + 1;          // count the newline!
    int rows = s.st_size / stride;     // all rows are the same length

    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            putchar(c[y*stride + x]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    munmap(c, s.st_size);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: A quick search around didn't turn up a much better way to handle this in C++ as far as I could tell.  I mean, I can add a typecast on the `mmap` line and change the `putchar` calls to `std::cout`, but that doesn't really seem like it makes any difference.

Comment: this does not seem to be an exercise on which low level OS construct to use but simply to traverse a file.

Comment: Yeah, and using `mmap` will be a lot easier than seeking all over the place.

Comment: It will be easier for you but for him.  This guy is a beginner.  Just look at his code.  Suggesting him to use mmap will only confuse him.

Comment: I'm pretty proficient with C and i haven't used mmap or heard of it before.  I've always done stuff like fsetpos and fgetpos and so forth.  I'm going to check out this mmap stuff.  Nice

Comment: mmap will have the best performance and least memory usage in this situation... buffering entire file in a data structure is slow and takes up too much memory space. seeking around the file is too slow and IO intensive.

Comment: Yup, that's why I suggested it.  Probably it's logically similar to what one might do by buffering or seeking, but letting the OS handle the details is often helpful.

Comment: Great if he's using a POSIX-ey system.

Answer (score 1):

Untested pseudo-code that may give you some ideas. Basically, load the whole file into a 2d vector of characters for easy access. It will use more memory than reading directly from the file but this won't matter unless the file is very big.

```
vector<vector<char>> filemap;
string line;
while (getline(filestream, line))
{
    filemap.push_back(vector<char>(line.begin(), line.end()));
}

for (int x = 0; x < XSIZE; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < YSIZE; y++)
    {
        filestream << filemap[y][x]; // note x/y are opposite way round in 2d vectors
    }
    filestream << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thie file is indeed very big

Comment: @Saksham If this isn't an exercise, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Just an overview, the code extracts values from the file and updates database. each character points to a certain type

Comment: @Saksham Why do you need to transpose the file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to seek() repeatedly in the source file it is much easier and faster to simply read in the whole source file then generate output from the in-memory contents.

This sounds an awful like like a class assignment, so I won't simply write the answer for you. However this should point you in the right way -- Some PseodoCode is included

To avoid pain, it should presumably be safe to assume some upper bound on line length and max lines, i.e.,

```
const int MaxLines = 100;
const int MaxLength = 80;

int lineno, linelength;

// array of char pointers for each line
char *lines[] = (*lines[])malloc(Maxlines * sizeof(char*));

// ReadLoop
lineno = 0;
while (not eof)
{
  getline(buffer);
  if (++lineno++ == 1)
  {
    linelength = strlen(buffer);
  }
  else
  {
    if (linelength != strlen(buffer))
    {
      cout "Line # " << lineno << " does not match the expected length";
      exit();
    }
  } 
  lines[lineno] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1));
  strcpy(lines[lineno], buffer);
}

int cc, linecnt = lineno;

// now all data in memory, output "vertical data"
for (cc = 0; cc < linelength; ++cc)
{
  for (lineno=0; lineno<<linelength; ++lineno)
  {
     cout << lines[xx][yy]; // xx && yy left you to figure out
  }
  cout "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why limit yourself to a hardset number of lines when it is easier and safer to use std data structures?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your file is not enormous, there's no reason not to just slurp the whole thing into memory. There may be a more idiomatic way to do this in C++, but the following works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::fstream infile("foo.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(infile,line)) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    int m=lines.size();
    int n=lines[0].length();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            std::cout << lines[j].at(i);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problems arise when all the lines in the file are not the same length, of course.

And now, a version that “doesn't use any extra memory” (of course, it does, but not much):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::fstream infile("foo.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    std::string line;
    std::getline(infile, line);
    int n = line.length();
    int m = 1+std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile),
           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');

    infile.clear();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            infile.seekg(j*m+i);
            std::cout << char(infile.peek());
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have written almost the exact code but i wish not to use extra memory for the operation. Anyways thanks!

Comment: @Saksham: why don't you want to use extra memory? How big is the file?

Comment: I may vary. maybe a thousand lines

Comment: @Saksham: if every line has 1000 characters, that's only a megabyte. The runtime performance of `seek()`-ing around a file of any size will be horrible. Much better to sacrifice few MB of memory, IMO. I added a “memory conserving” version to my answer, but I think it's an inferior solution.